# Using relative paths in bash file in docker container

Tags: docker

I have a fairly simple dockerfile that I need to expose a service to a port, such that users can netcat into it.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y socat 

# Change to strict permissions
RUN chmod 770 /bin/* /usr/bin/*
RUN chmod 771 /bin/cat /bin/ls /bin/sh /usr/bin/socat
# Add user bob
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/sh bob
EXPOSE 9000


# Add dir and change to working
RUN mkdir /home/bob/monster
WORKDIR /home/bob/monster


# copy working files and change permissions
COPY /files files


CMD ["sh","/home/bob/monster/files/start.sh"]
```

I then build and run with the two following commands:

```
 $ sudo docker build -t intmonster . 
 $ sudo docker run -p 9000:9000  --rm intmonster
```

Which all seems to work, except for the moment when I on my host system try to netcat to the service:

```
$ nc 0.0.0.0 9000
```

Which triggers this print in the terminal where the container is running:

```
$ sudo docker run -p 9000:9000  --rm intmonster
2022/01/01 22:59:53 socat[9] E execvp("./monster", "./monster"): No such file or directory
2022/01/01 22:59:53 socat[8] W waitpid(): child 9 exited with status 1
```

Where it looks like the "monster" directory cannot be found.

This seems strange to me, and therefore I want to do some testing.
For testing, I delete the last "CMD" line, and build again.
I now run again with the `-it` flag in order to play around inside the container.

I cd to the sh file that I want to run, and try to run it:

```
root@e3b83ca56f0b:/home/bob/monster/files# sh start.sh
```

This works, and I can netcat to it. I then try to `cd ..` and run the file from there. At first glance it works, but when I attempt to netcat to the service, I get the following error:

```
root@e3b83ca56f0b:/home/bob/monster# sh files/start.sh 
2022/01/01 23:51:15 socat[46] E execvp("./monster", "./monster"): No such file or directory
2022/01/01 23:51:15 socat[45] W waitpid(): child 46 exited with status 1
```

My theory is that this issue happens because the bash file runs a executable called "monster". When run from the home directory, the program looks in the relative path that the file is called from, instead of from the bash file itself.

How can I call the bash file from the home firectory, but still use relative paths in my bash file?

**EDIT:**

The "files" directory looks like this:

```
└── files
    ├── flag.txt
    ├── monster
    └── start.sh
```

Comment: you are running monster as `./monster`, so the PATH isn't relevant.  What matters is the directory your script (or whatever is running monster) is in when it tries to run it.   Is `monster` a directory or an executable (you've referred to it as both in your question, and your Dockerfile runs `/home/bob/monster`)?  If it's both and the `monster` executable is supposed to be in `/home/bob/monster` then whatever runs it needs to change directory to there before trying to run it as `./monster`.

Comment: The executable "monster" is in `/home/bob/monster/files`̉̉  `/home/bob/monster` is a directory. So the issue is that the command looks for the execuate in the home directory, while it is actually situated in the  `/home/bob/monster/files`̉̉ directory

Comment: It doesn't "look for" the file anywhere.  With `./monster`, you are explicitly telling it to execute a program called monster which is located in the current directory. No looking required and no searching will be done, the file is either where you said it is (`./`), or it is not.   For `./monster` to work, the calling program MUST be in the directory containing monster (`/home/bob/monster/files/`)

Comment: it is there, I have edited the question with the contents of the folder, both the "monster" exec is in `/home/bob/monster/files/` and the calling bash file. And it does not work. And yes, I'm aware that an actual search is not being performed, but the OS still looks for the file in that position

Comment: But however, as described in the question, the error will appear depending on wehter the file `start.sh` is called from the `/home/bob/monster/files/` or not, and thus it seems as if the bash is being run from another directory than `/home/bob/monster/files/`

Comment: I'll try one more time and then I'll give up.  The problem is not whether an executable called monster is in /home/bob/monster/files or not, at least not directly.   The problem is caused by the fact that the monster executable is NOT in the current working directory of whatever is running it.  If whatever that is changes directory to /home/bob/monster/files before trying to run it, then running `./monster` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned that the script works when you run it from `/home/bob/monster/files` directory. That is consistent with the error message, as the script seems to be looking for an executable in the same directory as itself (`execvp("./monster", "./monster")`).

However, in the dockerfile you only have `WORKDIR /home/bob/monster`, which is one level higher. Adding a second `WORKDIR` instruction should resolve the problem:

```
COPY /files files
WORKDIR files
```

This will place you inside `/home/bob/monster/files`, which will allow the script to work as expected.

Documentation for `WORKDIR` instruction: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir